# shell script having ssh command inside docker container fails with - ssh: not found

Tags: docker, ssh

I have a spring boot java application running on a docker container, and it tries to run a shell script. The shell script has a ssh command and I get the following error while running it

```
    2020-08-12 09:22:29.425  INFO 1 --- [io-11013-exec-1] b.n.i.s.d.e.service.EmrManagerService    : Executing spark submit, calling shell script: /tmp/temp843155675494688636.sh 172.29.199.15
    2020-08-12 09:22:29.434 DEBUG 1 --- [io-11013-exec-1] b.n.i.s.d.e.service.EmrManagerService    : Starting Input Stream:
    2020-08-12 09:22:29.435  INFO 1 --- [io-11013-exec-1] b.n.i.s.d.e.service.EmrManagerService    : #1 arg: 172.29.199.15
    2020-08-12 09:22:29.436  INFO 1 --- [io-11013-exec-1] b.n.i.s.d.e.service.EmrManagerService    : Exist Value127
    2020-08-12 09:22:29.436 ERROR 1 --- [io-11013-exec-1] b.n.i.s.d.e.service.EmrManagerService    : Starting Error Stream:
    2020-08-12 09:22:29.436 ERROR 1 --- [io-11013-exec-1] b.n.i.s.d.e.service.EmrManagerService    : 
    /tmp/temp843155675494688636.sh: line         5: ssh: not found
```

The same code works fine when am running the jar directly and not as docker container.
Is it something to do with ssh not recognized in docker container?

```
    shell script - 
    #!/bin/bash
    
    
    echo "#1 arg:" $1
    ssh -i /home/dnaidaasd/aws-oneid-idaas-2020Q2.pem -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no hadoop@$1 '/etc/alternatives/jre/bin/java -Xmx1000m -server \ 
    -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p" -cp "/usr/share/aws/emr/instance \
    -controller/lib/*" -Dhadoop.log.dir=/mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/s-100-120 \
    -Dhadoop.log.file=syslog -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/lib/hadoop \ 
    -Dhadoop.id.str=hadoop -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,DRFA -Djava.library.path=:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native \
    -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
    -Djava.io.tmpdir=/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-14611-353/tmp \
    -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender \
    -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=30 \
    org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-jars/command-runner.jar spark-submit \
    --conf spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compress=true \
    --conf spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
    --class biz.neustar.idaas.services.dataprofile.ProfileMain \
    --name IdaasProfile --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
    --conf spark.executor.instances=2 --conf spark.driver.memory=8G \
    --conf spark.executor.memory=4G --conf spark.executor.cores=1 \
    --conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive \
    --jars s3://oneid-idaas-dev-us-east-1/dev/emr/TestIdaasProfile/spark-core_2.11-2.4.5.jar,s3://oneid-idaas-dev-us-east-1/dev/emr/TestIdaasProfile/spark-sql_2.11-2.4.5.jar,s3://oneid-idaas-dev-us-east-1/dev/emr/TestIdaasProfile/spark-mllib_2.11-2.4.5.jar,s3://oneid-idaas-dev-us-east-1/dev/emr/TestIdaasProfile/jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.6.7.1.jar,s3://oneid-idaas-dev-us-east-1/dev/emr/TestIdaasProfile/jackson-databind-2.6.7.jar  s3://oneid-idaas-dev-us-east-1/dev/emr/TestIdaasProfile/data-profile-14.0.jar' \
    $2 $3 $4
```

This shell script is called as -

```
public void executeSparkSubmit(String masterNodeIp, String pathToScript, String input_hive_table, String s3_output_path,  String output_hive_table ) throws IOException, InterruptedException, DataProfileServiceException {

        log.info("Executing spark submit, calling shell script: " + pathToScript + " " + masterNodeIp);
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh", pathToScript, masterNodeIp, input_hive_table, s3_output_path, output_hive_table);
        Process pr = pb.start();
```

And the `Dockerfile` contents are:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD ./data-profile-provider/build/libs/data-profile-provider-203.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar data-profile.jar
EXPOSE 11013
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "data-profile.jar", "application.properties"]
```

Comment: It looks like there is not ssh client installed inside the container. What image is the container based on?

Comment: @KonradBotor The docker image is just a web application service . Does it answer your question?

Comment: No, it does not. I'd need either image name and tag if it's published on Docker Hub or Dockerfile it's built from if it's a custom one.

Comment: Its a custom image built.@KonradBotor

Comment: Then I'd need the Dockerfile to help you.

Comment: Try running `ssh` inside the container itself (assuming it can launch the container successfully.

Install into container using `sudo apt-get install ssh`, also might want to edit `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` - these are on Ubuntu 20.04 server.

Comment: FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ADD ./data-profile-provider/build/libs/data-profile-provider-203.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar data-profile.jar
EXPOSE 11013
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "data-profile.jar", "application.properties"]
Docker file @KonradBotor

Comment: Why is everyone assuming OP is using Debian-based container and why are you all advising them to install SSH server as well as client? If the OP was, in fact using Debian-based container, the proper command would have been `apt install openssh-client`. `ssh` is a meta-package for installing client and server at the same time: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ssh

Comment: @KonradBotor 
I did not assume at all that he uses Ubuntu, please read my answer again and see that although I said 'assume' I should have rephrased to 'My example here is based on an Ubuntu/Linux image'.  Strange how people misinterpret intentions lol.   Besides, my answer was before he added the Dockerfile contents in his answer. However, you are correct in that `ssh` installs the server as well; which is not required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I suspected - your image is Alpine-based and Alpine does not have SSH client installed by default.

Corrected `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client
ADD ./data-profile-provider/build/libs/data-profile-provider-203.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar data-profile.jar
EXPOSE 11013
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "data-profile.jar", "application.properties"]
```

Edit: I forgot to add that Alpine does not have Bash either. Luckily your app invokes your script with `sh scriptname.sh` - otherwise you'd get `bash: not found` error.

Comment: No problem. It'd be nice if you accepted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**SSH might not be installed.**

*My example here assumes an Ubuntu/Linux image derived from since you did not specify the Dockfile contents at the time.*

If your container can launch successfully (ignore the fact that your app is failing), you can just simply run `ssh` on the command-line to see (it will give you something similar to `command not found`)

To run commands inside Docker container:  *Since an Ubuntu image has bash installed, you can run like this:*

`docker exec -ti containername bash`

Inside Docker container: (One of my containers where there is no SSH installed)

```
  ssh
  ssh: command not found
```

The base container you inherit from might not have the tool installed.  Most Docker containers you inherit from are usually with 'bare minimum' in mind, so your custom Docker image needs to install it otherwise.

*Just adding the run command that you can add onto the Dockerfile, make sure your user are able to run these. (In this example I made sure the container image user is `root`)*  **This example installs only the ssh-client only (which is what is required)**

```
USER root

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install openssh-client

USER mydockercontaineruser
```